# How do you report a bug to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I'm trying to fuse 2 Facebook pages, in one particular case, in the last step, after choosing which page I want to keep for the fusion, Facebook undo my choice and set the other page with the confirmation box dialog. How can I report a bug like that to Facebook?

Comment: [Report a bug](https://www.facebook.com/help/440338062710823).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See](https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065?helpref=faq_content):

> **Report a Broken Feature**
>
> If something's not working on Facebook, please follow the instructions
>   below to let us know more. These instructions will show you how to
>   report a problem directly from the page you're seeing it on.
>
> How do I report a problem with Facebook?
>
> What happens when I report that something isn't working on Facebook?
>
> How do I take a screenshot?